# How/where are fstrings implemented?

Tags: python

How are fstrings implemented in Python?  I'm looking at the types via my IDE for strings and fstring variables have the same inferred type, `str`.  Is it a whole new class or implementing the same interface as string?  An explanation of how it works would be great.

The reason I ask is because I want to evaluate if it would be reasonable for us to implement our version.  Additionally, would it be possible to do it in such a way that IDEs would be able to infer different types based on the letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're implemented (in CPython anyway) somewhere over...

- [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ca7b504a4d4c3a5fde1ee4607b9501c2bab6e743/Parser/Python.asdl#L79) in the ASDL syntax definition
- [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a04ea4f92ccbe20ffdbb5fa9b6bb93ee8da50f5d/Python/ast.c#L4999) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a04ea4f92ccbe20ffdbb5fa9b6bb93ee8da50f5d/Python/ast.c#L4841) in the AST transformer as far as I can see
- [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9932a22897ef9905161dac7476e6976370e13515/Python/ast_opt.c#L542-L545) in an optimizer
- [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a04ea4f92ccbe20ffdbb5fa9b6bb93ee8da50f5d/Python/compile.c#L3945-L3947) in the compiler
- and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2f94730d947f25b8507c5f76202e917683e76f7/Python/ceval.c#L3618) in the actual runtime evaluator.

I may have missed some spots.

Based on this, I'd say adding other prefixes will be tough and you'd essentially be creating your own fork of Python.

Comment: ah ok, so its getting way deep in there huh?  Also probably to make it look like a string to the IDE and be optimized in C.  But does it actually _need_ all of those places to get the core functionality?  Like if we lower the bar to a smaller more narrow use case and essentially be some syntactic sugar for a normal function call when you do `g"asdf"`.   Is something like that easily possible?

Comment: Why not just `g("asdf")` then? If you want to be naughty, you can inject `g` into builtins too...

Comment: I was actually coming to that conclusion myself.  A couple extra `()` are worth the easier implementation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value. In Python source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with 'f', which contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with their values.

fstrings are implemented inside CPython - Processing them is essentially evaluating the expression enclosed within the curly braces, here's [one example from CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a04ea4f92ccbe20ffdbb5fa9b6bb93ee8da50f5d/Python/ast.c#L4996) where the expressions are being parsed.

We can use `dis` to observe the opcodes:

```py
import dis

dis.dis("f'{x}'")                                                                                                                    
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              4 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis("x")                                                                                                                     
              0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the only added opcode is `FORMAT_VALUE`, which confirms that there's no added overhead to fstrings and they are actually an expression, as opposed to `format` for example, where we see `LOAD_CONST`, `LOAD_ATTR` and `CALL_FUNCTION`:

```py
In [9]: dis.dis('"{}".format(x)')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('{}')
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (format)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```